# Is there a length limit for a HTML heading? (h1, h2 etc)

Tags: html

Is it valid HTML5 to have a long sentence as a `h2`?

For example:

```
<hgroup>
  <h1>
    Food & Drink Products
  </h1>
  <h2>
    There are 5000 food products near you in 100 categories from brands like FoodX, DrinkY, and FoodStuffsZ.
  </h2>
</hgroup>
```

Or would a `p` tag more appropriate?

I'm asking because the importance of this text is that of a `h2`, but it reads like a paragraph and I could not find an example like this or any mention of heading length on the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/).

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it's valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should mark up your text based on *what is appropriate for the content you are showing*, according to most copy-writing and SEO guidelines.

**There is no limit on heading length from a HTML perspective**, but you need to consider it from other, arguably more important, perspectives:

- **Readability & UX**: Headings that are too long can be difficult to read, and could therefore affect usability and users experience. It can also affect the overall appearance of the page and make it look unbalanced or as if you are trying to over-optimise the page which can give a poor impression to users.
- **Effectiveness**: The shorter and snappier a heading is (without losing meaning of course), the easier it is for users to take it in quickly and the better it gets the message across. That's why slogans and taglines work in marketing!
- **SEO**: We know that Google pays most attention to the first 60-70 characters in a page `title` which is generally the same as the `h1`. I don't know of any data about how they consider `h2` or any other subheadings, but their aim is to appraise pages in the same way humans do. So if they think that overly-long headings are not "user-friendly" then they might not rate it, or worse, penalise the page for attempting to "game" the SEO system.

**In summary**: As I mentioned earlier, the advice for usability, SEO and general copywriting is to do what makes sense for your own content. So if it makes sense then do it, but in most cases there is no need for long heading and it could a sign that the text needs improvement, and a shorter version would probably work better :)

**In the example in your question**, I wouldn't consider that text a heading - it sounds more like a paragraph. A heading would be something like "*5000 Food Products Near You in 100 Categories*", with the next text being info about the products and categories.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. i agree with your last sentence, that exact thought occurred to me while asking this question. and just to clarify, the text is styled like a paragraph, i was just curious about if using the h2 markup instead (but keeping the same styling) would somehow be bad practice. thanks again

Comment: @Benjamin If the text is styled like a paragraph, it sounds like it definitely makes more sense to have it marked up as a paragraph as that is it's apparent purpose in the content. The only reason to use `h2` in this case would be for SEO, but if it is long *and* styled like a paragraph that could be an indicator to Google that you are trying to be deceptive. (When it comes to Google, who really knows what they do? :) But its best to stick to the guidelines to be on the safe side).

Comment: sorry its actually styled slightly bigger than a paragraph (1.5rem of 16px). its obvious on viewing the page that it is a subheading of the `h1` and from the size and positioning it is clearly distinct from the main body text styling

Comment: @Benjamin In that case my original answer still applies! If it works as a sub heading with the rest of the text, then maybe just make it more heading-like by removing the "*There are*" at the start and check how the length is for readability. There are no hard and fast rules... Whatever works!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be precise, use `h1` or `h2` for headlines and `p` for paragraphs. Long headlines are fine, there's no rule saying headlines shouldn't be long.

Also, truth of the matter is, it doesn't matter so much. If you choose `p` over `h2`, as long as it works well for you, that's fine.

There are far more important things, such as writing a responsive website, clean code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

That definitely depends on what you want. If `h2` suffices for you use that. I myself would prefer to use `<p>` for that and then chance css for my liking.

Answer (score 2):

There are no problems to use headers as a paragraph, but the question is for what? If you just want to highlight the text, use a `p` with a class, it is much better